# How to customize style of AlertDialog across all versions?

Tags: android, styles

I try to make custom style for alert  dialog that will work acros 2.2 to 4.2 versions. The best approach that I found is to use

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
```

However it is available from API 11 would not work on versions older than that. Could you suggest the painless way to implement the alert dialog with custom style? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use android-support-v4.jar (you can read about this library from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html))

add this library in your libs folder and add it to build path

Now, for creating dialog,

Now convert extends your activity by [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) (it takes nothing, it is just a sub class of Activity)

Now you have to create a static inside your activity like :

```
public static class ReportNameFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.enter_report_name);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.enter_report_dialog, null);
        final EditText reportName = (EditText) view
                .findViewById(R.id.report_name);
        builder.setView(view)
                // Add action buttons
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.save,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                //Positive Button task

                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                ReportNameFragment.this.getDialog()
                                        .cancel();
                            }
                        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

And call this dialog from anywhere in your activity by writing :

```
DialogFragment reportNameFragment = new ReportNameFragment();
            reportNameFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    "reportNameTypePicker");
```

If you want to read more about dialogs, you can go [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about painless, but here is a way that works in my experience:

1) Create a custom view or layout and set it on your builder via builder.setView(view).

2) If you have AlertDialog buttons - those are not part of your custom view, they fire events for DialogInterface.OnClickListener and not View.OnClickListener. So if you need to style them, you have to do it dynamically like so when creating your actual alert:

```
    alert = builder.create();
    alert.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog)
        {
            Button btnPositive = alert.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            // set custom stuff for your positive button

            Button btnNegative = alert.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            // set custom stuff for your negative button
        }
    });
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but so far I've not found anything else that works as well for min API level 8.